# Wireless Access Point Without Physically Connecting DD-WRT Routers

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I have two routers running DD-WRT. The main one is connected to the modem which is on the second floor, and I would like to boost my wifi strength so my entire house is covered with wifi. I would like to place my second router on the first floor and turn it into a wireless access point.

I have been looking at [tutorials](http://www.dd-wrt.ca/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) and all of them require both routers to be physically connected via a network cable. Is there a way for the routers to not be connected via a network cable and instead be connected via wifi signal?

In addition, I would like the computers that connect to the second router to also be able to see my homegroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DD-WRT supports a [number of router linking modes](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers), including the [repeater bridge mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge):

> New in DD-WRT v24 is Repeater Bridge mode. This extends your primary LAN via secondary router (bridge router) and also allows wireless clients to connect to your secondary router. This extends the range of your wireless network while simultaneously allowing wired clients to connect to your secondary router.

Note that recent version of DD-WRT is required. Moreover, the wireless bandwidth on your secondary router will be essentially halved (since all wireless traffic will have to be re-broadcast again, wirelessly. Also, it appears that both routers will be on the same channel, which is sub-optimal.

In conclusion, it can be done, but if you can run the network cable to the secondary router, your network will have better bandwidth and be more stable.

Comment: Thank you. When my second router is using the Repeater Bridge will my devices automatically select the faster router?

Comment: Unforunately, Wi-Fi roaming is far from perfect... In theory, yes, your wireless device should connect to the router with a stronger signal, and it should work for stationary devices pretty well. However, switchover will cause your mobile device to loose network connection for a few seconds, so many devices will not switch until a weaker router goes out of range completely.

Comment: Thanks. Lastly, I am wondering how would I verify that my secondary router is acting as an access point other then saying that the signal has become stronger. Should I be able to access the router (by going to 192.0.1.2) and checking if it has an IP address?

Comment: Yeah you setup your secondary router as usual (IP address etc.) You will be able to see connected clients on its status page.